# JDK 7 java.nio.file isSymbolicLink() behavior

Tags: java, java.nio.file

I am trying to use  the  **FileWalkTree()** method in JDK 7 (java.nio.file) .
To implement my own FileVisitor I have created a **CustomFileVIsitor** class by extending **SimpleFileVisitor**.

In this **CustomFileVIsitor** class .... I am overriding the function **visitFile**

```
             public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes fileStats)
        throws IOException {
                              System.out.println("\t\tChecking Symbolic Link  " + Files.isSymbolicLink(file));
                      System.out.println("\t\tChecking Symbolic Link  " + fileStats.isSymbolicLink());
                         System.out.println("\t\tFile Size " + Files.size(file));
                     System.out.println("\t\tFile Size " + fileStats.size());
                             //Rest of the code
             }
```

Now,to test this code,  I have created a folder and then I added a file and a symbolic link (to a file) to it.

When I execute the class with FileWalkTree the output generated by Files.isSymbolicLink(file) and fileStats.isSymbolicLink() for the symbolic link is different

The output looks like this:

```
            Checking Symbolic Link  true
            Checking Symbolic Link  false
            File Size 38
            File Size 38
```

Why is it so ? Is it a bug or is there something I am missing in interpreting the information ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are obtaining the file attributes via a call similar to

```
FileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(path, FileAttributes.class);
```

if that is so, you probably need to prevent the resolution of the symlink by passing in the appropriate `LinkOption` enumeration, like so

```
FileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(path, FileAttributes.class, NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
```

Odds are you have resolved the link obtaining your `FileAttributes`, which would explain why the `File`reports it is a symlink while the `FileAttributes` reports it is not a symlink.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... You are right My Initial code was      `Files.walkFileTree(toolVersionPath, EnumSet.of(FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS), Integer.MAX_VALUE,preScanVisitorObject);`    and now I have changed to `Files.walkFileTree(toolVersionPath, EnumSet.noneOf(FileVisitOption.class), Integer.MAX_VALUE,preScanVisitorObject);`  and now it returns file is symbolic link in both the cases .......